# Using iCloud Mail account from Computers without Lion?

Tags: mail.app, mobileme, icloud

If I understand correctly, MobileMe Mail will only work in the future under ICloud. For iCloud you need iOS 5 or Lion on an actual computer.

I have 4 Apple computers currently in use, I use mail on whatever computer I am on. Only one has Snow Leopard which can upgrade to Lion. One has Leopard and 2 have Tiger.

Does anyone know if at least one computer has the most updated OS that the information will show up on other computers?

I am not interested in an iPhone or iPad for email use since I require a full keyboard and tend to write lengthly emails.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you get to keep MobileMe as it is until June 30, 2012.

Sometime between when iCloud launches (tomorrow?) and next June, you can choose to learn about and use iCloud (assuming it meets all your current and future needs) or find another email provider.

It is clear that Apple has said you will lose access to you me.com account if you don't move to iCloud by then so unless that changes, you should plan some action.

If things go as planned, we will all get a public look at things this week. Perhaps read some official documentation in the next month you. The future is unclear today before iCloud has launched, but you have 9+ months to worry about this...

Comment: For the record, you can access iCloud via IMAP on machines that do not have Lion.

Comment: I'll gladly write up a comprehensive answer once a public launch is made and if no-one else has stepped up with all the details for access to calendar / email and other things likely to be standards based and support legacy products.

Answer (score 1):

MobileMe is going away with iCloud, it will last in its current form until some time next year.

The email from iCloud should be pretty standard like it is now, so therefore older mail clients should be able to use it - but you may have to upgrade one of your machines to enable iCloud.

So if you are asking if your mac.com/me.com email address will continue to work - yes, it should, as long as you convert to iCloud. You should then be able to set it up as an IMAP account on your older computers. This may not be a supported setup (so may be harder to get help if you need it)

As far as calendaring and all the other features of iCloud, you won't be able to use without Lion or iOS 5.

Comment: For the record, you can access iCloud via IMAP on machines that do not have Lion.